# Google Analytics, Event Label Rename

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Sometimes back i had implemented Google Tagging, and i had used naming convention for the same, now i wanted to change the Naming convention,

so ,

1. how this will effect on my previous data
2. I wanted to change the previous data event label for the all the data, else it will be pain to Analysis data,

Guys please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: 2) you cannot change the previously collected data, 1) is off-topic.

Comment: This is off topic as it's not about coding, but to comment, you can't change past data, so you will just have to live with what you already have. If you change the names going forward, you could put in an annotation.

Comment: @nyuen thanks, can you please enlighten on the annotation ?